# Selecting sequence number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a table tab1 which have 2 columns. The values would be like below

```
SL_NO     CAL_DATE
807        2012-03-18
808        2012-03-19
....
1170       2013-03-16
```

I need to select from this table between the range of sl_no is 807 and 1170. Apart from this, i need to select 2 derived columns for a week_no_of_month and week_no_of_year.

week_no_of_month will be first 7 days fall in week 1, next 7 days in week 2 like 4 weeks in a period. Then again it has to initialise from week no 1 till it reaches 4 for every 7 days.

week_no_of_year will start from 1 and it will keep continue for every 7 days till it reaches 52.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Please let me know if need more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you need. This will answer your question, but I suspect that this is not a question that should have been asked:

```
select datediff (day, 
                 convert(varchar(4), year(CAL_DATE)) + '0101', 
                 CAL_DATE) / 7 + 1 WeekOfYear,
       (day(CAL_DATE) - 1) / 7 + 1 WeekOfMonth
```

You might take a look at [week numbering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) provided by Sql Server.

**UPDATE**:

```
declare @startOfFiscalYear as datetime
set @startOfFiscalYear = '20120318'

select datediff (day, 
                 @startOfFiscalYear, 
                 CAL_DATE) / 7 + 1 WeekOfYear,
       ((datediff (day, @startOfFiscalYear, CAL_DATE)) / 7 % 4) + 1 WeekOfMonth
```

WeekOfYear is simply day of year divided by seven. WeekOfMonth is day of year divided by seven and then by four leaving modulus only.

Comment: I am considering the fiscal calender. Here 2012-03-18  is the first day of the year and week number is 1

Comment: @Robinclave How do you identify this date to be starting point? SL_NO = 807 seems a bit vague. Also, what version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: We have a fiscal calender (hardcopy). From this we know this is the first day of the year. From this date, I have to polulate the other week number using the mentioned logic. SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Robinclave There are 364 (from 18. to 16.) days in fiscal year? What do you do with this four days extra? I.E. is each month having 30 days?

Comment: @Robinclave Please disregard my last comment and check the UPDATE part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the built-in DATE_PART week, maybe you can use that?

```
SELECT DATEPART( WEEK , 'May 2, 2012')
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e93ae/2

---

Re :

> The week number here should start from 1 for the first record which
>   i'm fetching within this range. this is not the normal calender week
>   number

Try this:

```
SELECT 

z.filter_date, x.d, 

(datediff(day,z.filter_date, x.d) / 7) + 1 as week_number

from x
cross join (select convert(date,'march 7, 2012') as filter_date) as z
where x.d >= z.filter_date
```

Data:

```
create table x(i int identity(1,1) primary key, d date);

insert into x(d) values
('February 2, 2012'),
('February 5, 2012'),
('March 7, 2012'),
('April 8, 2012'),
('May 9, 2012'),
('June 9, 2012');
```

Output:

```
FILTER_DATE D               WEEK_NUMBER
2012-03-07  2012-03-07      1
2012-03-07  2012-04-08      5
2012-03-07  2012-05-09      10
2012-03-07  2012-06-09      14
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4837/12